# Why can I not add new bookmarks to a Firefox bookmarks folder?

Tags: 12.04, firefox

I not able to add new bookmarks to a Firefox bookmarks folder. This bookmarks folder contains a lot of entries. Is that the cause? If so, what should I do?
PS I run Firefox 26 under Ubuntu Precise.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the Bookmarks file, there may be an issue that your bookmarks file is write-protected.

Click on the Help menu and select Troubleshooting Information. Once open look under the Application Basics section, click on Open Directory, and a window with your profile files will open.  Once you get that done, you need to exit Firefox.

Find and right click on the `places.sqlite` file, select Properties, and make sure that the file is NOT Read-only.  Once done restart Firefox, and see if it works.  Seem images below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]